# How to sort excel spreadsheet (KENDO UI)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

when i download excel file, my spreadsheet has not sorting.

maybe you know about it ?

Help please (

```js
vm.gridOptionsUpdate = {
            excel: {
              allPages: true,
              fileName: 'rates-upload.xlsx'
              //sort: { field: "rate", dir: "desc" } // i need somthing like that
            },
            excelExport: function (e) {
...
}
 sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    selectable: 'multiple cell',
    allowCopy: true,
    reorderable: true,
    columns: [
      {
        field: 'rate',
        title: 'Current Rate (EUR/SMS)',
        format: '{0:n4}'
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [saveAsExcel](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid.html#methods-saveAsExcel) API method to get the sorting and filtering applied in your UI to the zip created with the excel document. A good tutorial on this from the authors (KendoUI) can be found at:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export

Comment: why? i use <div kendo-grid k-options="vm.gridOptionsUpdate" k-data-source="vm.dataSourceUpdate"></div>
and define btn into the script : toolbar: kendo.template("<a class='k-grid-excel' title='Download Result'></a>") for downloading

Comment: Because that is what the documentation says. Without using that method you do not get the sorting, filtering, grouping, and aggregates applied. What method are you calling? @AxOn

Comment: i call var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); grid.dataSource.sort({field: "rate", dir: "asc"}); grid.saveAsExcel(); Thanks, that is working